# Resizing an image to minimum dimensions in Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip to resize an imported image, and I want the image to be a minimum of 465x465, so I've set the following style in my model:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :cropped => ["465x465^", :jpg]}
```

As I understood the ImageMagick documentation, and various other questions and answers on Stack Overflow, the caret(^) should mean that if the image width or height is smaller than those minimum dimensions, it's resized to meet them and also maintain aspect ratio.

The trouble I'm having is that I'm importing images that exceed both the width and height, in which case I'd expect ImageMagick to leave it alone, but it's resizing the smaller dimension (width if it's a portrait image, height if it's landscape) to 465px - does anyone know why that might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the documentation of imagemagick, it looks like you're looking at the `<` flag :

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#enlarge

I didn't try it, but it should work

Comment: I've given it a try, but it seems like that flag isn't all that useful, it'll only resize a small image if both dimensions are smaller than the specified ones (465 in this case).

Comment: It looks like you'd need some sort of condition then, maybe doing it with a lambda? https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation. You could test for original size and determine which flag to apply according to it ... would it work?

Comment: That's a good idea actually - now to figure out how to write a conditional for this :D Thanks for the tip!